# numpy matrix subtraction gives very small number where it should give zero

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra

I have the following code:

```
A = np.random.randint(-10,10,(4,4))
B = np.random.randint(-10,10,(4,4))
A1, A2, A3, A4 = inv(A@B), inv(A)@inv(B), inv(B@A), inv(B)@inv(A)
print(A1 - A4)
```

since mathematically A1 = A4, subtracting them should give back zero matrix, but I get

```
[[-1.73472348e-18  1.73472348e-18  3.46944695e-18  3.46944695e-18]
 [-8.67361738e-19  0.00000000e+00  4.01154804e-18  3.46944695e-18]
 [ 3.46944695e-18  1.73472348e-18  3.46944695e-18 -3.46944695e-18]
 [-1.73472348e-18 -1.73472348e-18 -1.73472348e-18  1.73472348e-18]]
```

its very close to zero, but not really zero - why is that?

Comment: My guess would be floating point precision https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)